# What Do SegWit Addresses Look Like?

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, bitcoin-cli

Probably a question that has been asked a lot before, but how do I know if an address I generate with bitcoind and bitcoin-cli is SegWit?

I take the following steps to (attempt to) generate a SegWit address with the command prompt:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -testnet getnewaddress

n2BC24zr3L5BwVazecnvPPh7NwgcV2Vfxa

$ bitcoin-cli -testnet -addwitnessaddress n2BC24zr3L5BwVazecnvPPh7NwgcV2Vfxa

2NBnkQpnPitDbE3evwZXGpNpRLE51cJpdGA
```

Now this confuses me because [in this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6vq5ef/is_it_possible_to_distinguish_check_normal_btc/) it is stated that SegWit addresses start with a '3'. Yet in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/7fnuqh/how_to_check_transactions_of_a_segwit_address/) address it is said that they start with 'bc'.

The address I've generated in the above example starts with 2N, which is neither of the above. How can I know if it is still SegWit? Or did I do something wrong while trying to make a SegWit address?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the testnet which uses 2 instead of 3, but as far as i know it is impossible to tell if something is a multisig or segwit adress when they both start with 3 on the "real" bitcoin chain, It could be both..

However you can indeed be sure that it is a segwit adress when they start with BC1, these are so called bech adresses. See more here, https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki

Comment: I generated the address as shown above: I first call 'getnewaddress' which returns the n2B address. Then I use that address as a seed for the 'addwitnessaddress' which gives me the 2N address. Is it because I am doing all this on the testnet, perhaps?

Comment: Ah yes, 2N is indeed the default for the testnet. See https://testnet.smartbit.com.au/tx/d529ccb7c17557bb784e410bfffc1bf57b60991b86eb0f48028369182491c0fb for example